# Duplicate Menu Items VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

anyone ever run into this issue with VS 2012?

[image: Duplicate menus]

I've tried resetting my development environment back to default and that did not resolve anything. This is really frustrating.

Comment: You could check View->Toolbars->Customize. The Tab "Commands" there is a "Reset All" Function, did you already try that?

Comment: yes I checked that. that did not resolve my issue

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem in Visual studio 2011. I fixed it using /setup.
I'm still in the dark about the cause. DevEpxress? ReSharper? VSCommands? The combination?

The fix:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE>devenv.exe /safemode /setup
```

after that I started Visual Studio:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE>devenv
```

Comment: This worked for me. I didn't have any of those add-ins installed. My computer did shut down unexpectedly the previous time I had Visual Studio.Net 2013 open.

Answer (score 1):

I just resolved the issue by deleting the  devenv.CTM

From the path   **C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\1033**

Hope this will  help.

Answer (score 1):

Seems answer to this a bit deeper than people says above. Need to delete registry key and the config file and perform application reset to apply solid fix:

(Paths are question of version ran, but I'm sure who ever reads this can figure what path their installations are at.)

File: `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\<version>\12.0\<countrycode>\WDExpress.CTM`

Registry Key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\<version>\<vernum>_Config\Menus`

Express: `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio <vernum>.0\Common7\IDE\WDExpress.exe" /resetuserdata`

Other Versions: `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio <vernum>.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /resetuserdata`

This seems to fix the issue permanently (used 60 mins, lol, what a waste).

Answer (score -2):

Open cmd in admin mode 
Change dir to dev instal path
Run below command . ( but it will reset your initial settings , like c# preference  setting on starting – that’s not a big issue I think )

Devenv.exe /resetuserdata